# How do I reference Vue components in my NPM linked Nuxt plugin?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a custom Nuxt module which is NPM linked and adds a plugin like so:

```
import path from 'path'

export default function (moduleOptions) {
  this.addPlugin(path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'))
}
```

This is fine, the plugin then imports a relative Vue component and adds to the router like so:

```
import ProductListing from './components/ProductListing.vue'

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  app.router.addRoutes([
    {
      path: '/products',
      name: 'products',
      component: ProductListing,
      meta: {
        permissions: ['manage_catalogue']
      }
    }
  ])
}
```

When I run `npm run dev` I get the error:

```
This relative module was not found:                                                                                       friendly-errors 16:48:40
                                                                                                                          friendly-errors 16:48:40
* ./components/ProductListing.vue in ./.nuxt/src.plugin.2237471c.js
```

[image]

Which kind of makes sense because it's trying to find it in the relation to the .nuxt folder, but I can't work out how I'm meant to get it to resolve the component? If I move the module/plugin into the `modules` folder in the Nuxt project it's fine.

### What I've tried

Tried adding webpack config to not resolve symlinks

```
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      Object.assign(config.resolve, {
        symlinks: false
      })
    }
```

I've tried adding the module to the transpile build option like this:

```
  build: {
    transpile: [
      '@symlinked/module'
    ]
  }
```

I've tried compiling the module to commonjs with webpack and vue loader, that just gives an entirely different error about templates.

---

At this point I'm a bit at a loss of what to do and was hoping someone has had a similar situation and overcome it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `ProductListing` inside your plugin and import it, you must add `PluginListings.vue` as a Template in your module. adding a file as a template says to nuxt you must copy this file into `.nuxt` directory

```js
import path from 'path'

export default function (moduleOptions) {
  // add ProductListing as template
  this.addTemplate(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ProductListing.vue'))

  // register plugin
  this.addPlugin(path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'))
}
```